Nmcli and nmtui can't read password for wifi network
Ubuntu 23.10 here. When using Network Manager in KDE, I can connect to the wifi network via the Network Manager applet. Connections are saved with passwords so I don't need to enter a password for every connection.
But the problem appears when I try to activate the connection from the command line, when KDE is not running, from a virtual console (like ctrl+alt+f4). I can list configured connections but when I try to activate the Wi-Fi connection nmtui asks me for a password. Same nmcli. Passwords for my wifi network are saved in configuration files in /run/NetworkManager/system-connections.
How to activate connection from cli without typing password and use password from config file?

I added bug report for Network Manager https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/2065346
